# RadioButton.clearCheck throwing an error

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have a program where when a button is clicked, radiobuttons change text. I also want the radiobuttons to all be deselected after the button is pressed. I have the following code in my onClickListener:

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PreviousScore = score;

            Score.setText(String.valueOf(action()));
            i++;
            question1();
            Button mRadioGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            mRadioGroup.clearCheck();

    }
```

I am getting the following error: "Cannot Resolve Method" on .clearCheck().

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Because **Button** doesn’t have method **clearCheck**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"Cannot Resolve Method" on mRadioGroup.clearCheck();`. Because [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) doesn’t have method `clearCheck`. But [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) has `clearCheck` method.

Use

```
RadioGroup mRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
mRadioGroup.clearCheck();
```

Intead of

```
Button mRadioGroup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
mRadioGroup.clearCheck();
```